# С++ нарушение прав доступа

Tags: c++, sdl

Пытаюсь освоить новый для себя c++ и пишу приложение "blackjack". На данный момент уже долгое время ломаю голову над этой ошибкой - 
Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x00CCA4F9 в ConsoleApplication3.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу 0x0000000C.

Ошибка пошла после данных строчек кода

Файл game.cpp

```
struct Card{
    SDL_Texture* texture;
    SDL_Rect* rect;
    SDL_Surface* surf;
};
Card deck[2];
int cardsInDeck = 0;
SDL_Rect cardSrc, cardDest;
int cardWidth = 32;
int cardHeight = 64;
...
void Game::addCard(const char* path, int xpos, int ypos)
{
    deck[cardsInDeck].surf = IMG_Load(path);
    deck[cardsInDeck].texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, deck[cardsInDeck].surf);
    deck[cardsInDeck].rect->h = cardHeight;
    deck[cardsInDeck].rect->w = cardWidth;
    deck[cardsInDeck].rect->x = xpos;
    deck[cardsInDeck].rect->y = ypos;
    SDL_FreeSurface(deck[cardsInDeck].surf);
    cardsInDeck++;
}
```

Файл main.cpp

```
game->addCard("assets/AS.png", 100, 100);
```

Полный код на [GITHUB](https://github.com/DGLeming/cpp_error/tree/master/ConsoleApplication3)

Comment: На Гитхабе в main.cpp нет вызова game->addCard

Answer (score 4):

Что тут голову ломать: очевидный доступ через null-указатель. Скорее всего на

```
deck[cardsInDeck].rect->h = cardHeight;
```

То есть у вас в этот момент `deck[cardsInDeck].rect` - нулевой указатель. Смещение поля `SDL_Rect::h` равно, если я не ошибаюсь, `12`, т.е. `0xC`. Это и есть ваша "запись по адресу 0x0000000C".

В честь чего у вас поле `Card::rect` вообще является *указателем*? Это намеренно так сделано? И если это сделано намеренно, то вам сначала надо позаботиться о том, чтобы этот указатель куда-то указывал.

Comment: +1 за интерпретацию низкоуровневых деталей :)